# CTE, Incorrect syntax near ';' SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I've written such PROCEDURE in Sql Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_SelectDatesFromRange
(
    @startDate DATETIME,
    @endDate DATETIME
)
AS
(
    ;WITH dates AS
    (
        SELECT @startDate AS [Date]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [Date])
        FROM dates
        WHERE [Date] <= @endDate - 1
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM dates
);
```

It should return all dates, between two, given parameters. But I can't run it, it gives me an error.

```
Incorrect syntax near ';'
Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

This errors are at the beginning of 'with', an at the end of code of procedure.

I'm learning CTE, so sorry, if this is obvious mistake.

Please help, thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that your error has anything to do with CTEs per se, but rather you are trying to use parentheses to denote the body of your stored procedure.  Either drop the parentheses, or possibly use a `BEGIN` and `END` block:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_SelectDatesFromRange
(
    @startDate DATETIME,
    @endDate DATETIME
)
AS

BEGIN

    ;WITH dates AS
    (
        SELECT @startDate AS [Date]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [Date])
        FROM dates
        WHERE [Date] <= @endDate - 1
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM dates
END;
```

Comment: I can't mark it until 6 minutes, I've tried but I can't

Comment: The BEGIN/END is not needed for valid syntax. The OP issue was the extraneous parenthesis.

Comment: @DanGuzman I slightly edited my answer.  I don't spend too much time working with procs in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.DateRange  
    @start datetime,   
    @end datetime  
AS  
    with cte as 
    ( SELECT @start as strtDt, @end as endDt
      union all 
      select strtDt + 1, endDt 
      from cte 
      where strtDt < endDt
    )
select * from cte
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. You have `DROP` and `CREATE` in the same batch and `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be the only statement in the batch.

Comment: Or add a `GO` batch terminator :-)